# create css class on the fly in codebehind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, asp.net-3.5

I have a search page that is used in multiple places with multiple 'themes' throughout my site. I have a few divs that can have their background color changed based on a radio button selection (whether they are enabled or not). I can do this just fine by changing the css class of the div on the fly with javascript.

However, these themes could potentially change, and the background color is grabbed from a database when the page is created. Right now I do this in the C# codebehind:

```
string bgStyle = "background-color:" +theme.searchTextHeaderColor +";";
OwnerSearchHeader.Attributes.Add("style", bgStyle);
```

In the Javascript I need to change this color to make it look disabled, and when the user clicks back to this div I need to re-enable it by changing it back to its original color. But since I only knew this color in the code-behind, I don't know what it was in the Javascript.

So my thought was to create a css class in the resulting HTML page when the page is loaded with the background color I need. Then I could simply switch from the divEnabled and divDisabled class in the javascript. But I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

Alternatively I could create a hidden element, assign it the 'enabled' style, and use that as a reference in the JavaScript when enabling my div. This seems like a hack but maybe its the easiest way. I'm still new to a lot of this, so I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my thought was to create a css class in the resulting HTML page when the page is loaded with the background color I need. Then I could simply switch from the divEnabled and divDisabled class in the javascript. But I'm not exactly sure how to do that.

Yes, this is the anser; do this. In the `<head>` of your document add a `<style>` and put your CSS in there like so: (my Asp.NET is a little rusty so forgive me if it has some hicups ;) )

```
<style>
    <!--
    .divEnabled {
        background-color:<%=theme.searchTextHeaderColor%>;
    }
    .divDisabled {
        background-color:gray; /* or wtv */
    }
    -->
</style>
```

You could also put it in an external CSS file, which may be a good idea.

Then write some JavaScript to add/remove the class attribute (I'm going to ask that you [don't call is the "CSS Class"](http://richard.jp.leguen.ca/not-blog/a-css-class) ;) )

```
var ownersearchheader = document.getElementById("<%=OwnerSearchHeader.ClientId%>");
// changing the class attribute to `divDisabled`
var newClassAttribute = ownersearchheader.getAttribute("class").replace(/\bdivEnabled\b/, "divDisabled")
ownersearchheader.setAttribute("class", newClassAttribute);
// ... or,
// changing the class attribute to `divEnabled`
var newClassAttribute = ownersearchheader.getAttribute("class").replace(/\bdivDisabled\b/, "divEnabled")
ownersearchheader.setAttribute("class", newClassAttribute);
```

This is indeed a mouthfull, so, like @Haydar says, you might want to use jQuery, which offers easy-as-pie `addClass()`, `removeClass()` and `toggleClass()` methods.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I thankfully already have the javascript written to swap the classes, so that's not a problem. I was more concerned with creating the css in the first place based on the theme. I do have a separate .css file, but I cannot modify that because it is used sitewide, and each of the instances of this page will have different themes, and thus different background colors. I don't think I can bind using <%=theme.searchTextHeaderColor%> in the css file...

Comment: You could bind like that in the CSS file if you changed it to a `.aspx` file... but that may be overkill.

Comment: Yes Richard, this is what you have to do as far as I can tell. You can't actually use the <%= %> code block in a css definition.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery .toggleClass method.

> Description: Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the value of the switch argument.

Here is the link to the api doc.
[Jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)